# Martin Gardner - Persistence

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, reachability

> **A [number's persistence](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/martin-gardners-hardest-puzzle-4334900.html) is :**
>
> - The number of steps required to reduce it to a single digit by multiplying all its digits to obtain a second number
> - Then multiplying all the digits of that number to obtain a third number, and so on until a one-digit number is obtained.

**For example** : 77 has a persistence of four because it requires four steps to reduce it to one digit: 77→49→36→18→8.

*The smallest number of persistence one is 10*

*The smallest of persistence two is 25*

*The smallest of persistence three is 39*

*The smaller of persistence four is 77*

> What is the smallest number of persistence five?

Comment: Wikipedia knows everything: [Persistence of a number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number)

Comment: Wow. All hail the **greatest** Wiki.

Comment: Fun fact; Any multiple of 9, when reducing to a single digit with this method, will return 9!

Comment: @warspyking: Am I missing something? 18 is a multiple of 9. When applying this I multiply all its digits to get 8. 8 is not equal to 9.

Comment: I think he means the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I forgot to mention instead of multiplying you have to add lol.

Comment: Sorry guys, adding the link to the original.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brute forcing with Lua gave me

> 679

This is also confirmed by Wikipedia and OEIS:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number

http://oeis.org/A003001

Answer (score 3):

This is a list of the smallest numbers of persistence $n$ with  ($1\leq n\leq11)$.

**1** 10

**2** 25

**3** 39

**4** 77

**5** 679  ---> (answer of this problem)

**6** 6788

**7** 68889

**8** 2677889

**9** 26888999

**10** 3778888999

**11** 277777788888899